# Why is IE letting a URL link break its container div?

Tags: css, browser, html, internet-explorer, hyperlink

Shows fine in FF, (continues the URL down to the next line, nice and clean). But IE lets it break passed the right border of the div.

The NEWS section of this page:

http://www.albuquerquecupcakecreations.com/index.php

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the URL in question also does not wrap in Safari, Chrome, or Opera. I suspect that Firefox is behaving contrary to standard here, although given the vagaries of browser compliance I could be wrong.

Comment: Also, is there supposed to be an underline on visited links? It looked out of place to me.

Comment: word-wrap to the rescue! thx for the thoughts m.

Comment: yea i just started my "make it work and not look too horrible in IE" phase. thanks for thoughts lucas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate having to write browser-specific code but there is a specific CSS property for IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
word-wrap: break-word; 
<![endif]-->
```

All the best

Comment: works great! thanks so much man, really appreciate it. i didnt even bother with a condition, it looks great in both browsers now. :D

Answer (score 0):

In the similar `<li>` which begins 'Love This', IE is breaking at the ? character in the url. There is no ? in the problem url. I added one (like this: `http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2339?2152480352_1b5ee54c44.jpg`) just to see what would happen, and the url wrapped nicely. Of course, then the url is not valid...

This isn't a fix, but maybe it will give you or someone else a clue.

A workaround would be to use simpler text for the display with the full url only in the href:

`<a href='http://long_complicated_url'>Click here for video</a>`